# How to get attributes from xml/scxml

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to get the attributes from "state" and "transition" in an scxml file using LINQ expressions.

Here's the scxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scxml xmlns:musthave="http://musthave.com/scxml/1.0" version="1.0" initial="Start" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/07/scxml">
    <state id="abc" musthave:displaystate="abcd" musthave:attribute1="None" musthave:attribute2="None">
        <transition attribute3="blabla" attribute4="blabla" xmlns=""/>
    </state>
    <state id="bla" musthave:displaystate="ababab" musthave:attribute2="View" musthave:attribute1="View"/>
</scxml>
```

Here's what I'm doing:

```
var scxml = XDocument.Load(@"c:\test_scmxl.scxml");
```

If I print on the console it shows me:

```
<scxml xmlns:musthave="http://musthave.com/scxml/1.0" version="1.0" initial="Start" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/07/scxml">
    <state id="abc" musthave:displaystate="abcd" musthave:attribute1="None" musthave:attribute2="None">
        <transition attribute3="blabla" attribute4="blabla" xmlns=""/>
    </state>
    <state id="bla" musthave:displaystate="ababab" musthave:attribute2="View" musthave:attribute1="View"/>
</scxml>
```

I'm trying to get all "states" like this:

```
foreach (var s in scxml.Descendants("state"))
{
     Console.WriteLine(s.FirstAttribute);
}
```

And when I print it to see if I get the id="abc", in this example, it doesn't return anything.

Although, if I run the code:

```
foreach (var xNode in scxml.Elements().Select(element => (from test in element.Nodes() select test)).SelectMany(a => a))
{
     Console.WriteLine(xNode);
     Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n");
}
```

It shows me:

```
<state id="abc" musthave:displaystate="abcd" musthave:attribute1="None" musthave:attribute2="None" xmlns:musthave="http://musthave.com/scxml/1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/07/scxml">
  <transition attribute3="blabla" attribute4="blabla" xmlns="" />
</state>



<state id="bla" musthave:displaystate="" musthave:attribute2="View" musthave:attribute1="View" xmlns:musthave="http://musthave.com/scxml/1.0"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/07/scxml" />
```

Any idea of how to do it?

**Note:** I've already read many articles and tried to do as suggested there, but nothing seems to work until now.

**Edit:** It doesn't get any attribute, just as the "First Attribute".

```
foreach (var state in scxml.Descendants("state"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(state.Attribute("id"));
}
```

**Edit:** The following code doesn't work either. Console warns about the null possibility (suppressible). Nothing gets returned.

```
foreach (var state in scxml.Root.Descendants("state"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(state.Attribute("id"));
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't manage to figure out where the problem can be.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek , "IDeveloper" has a good solution. Just for you to know. =)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate that :) I would not come to this solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a namespace in your `scxml` tag, so you need to use it with your inner tags to get access to them. Here's a code you need:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/07/scxml";
foreach (var state in xdoc.Descendants(ns + "state"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(state.Attribute("id").Value);
}
```